# Playwright: How to select element inside other element that has text

Tags: playwright

So I run into a problem with selecting an element within another element that contains text.

I have a list item, within the list item I have a link with a text and a button. So I try to do this like:

```
const listItem = this.page.locator('data-test-id=list-item:has-text('someText')') 
const button = listItem.locator("data-test-id=button")
await button.click()
```

But it does not really do the trick and the element is not being found. What am I missing here?

Comment: Showing an example of your HTML or page would be useful. Any number of complex, arbitrary, page-specific behaviors might cause the element not to be found. Your script might be blocked, iframes may be present, or visibility may not be available, preventing the click action for reasons other than the selector/locator logic. Even if the locator logic is incorrect, there's no way to guess what the correct version may be without some reference markup to work from.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```js
const listItem = this.page.locator('data-test-id=list-item', { hasText: 'someText' })
const button = listItem.locator("data-test-id=button")
await button.click()
```

Answer (score 2):

[Locator Filters](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-filter) are very useful in this scenario:

```
const listItems = this.page.locator('data-test-id=list-item');
// ...
await listItems
    .filter({ hasText: 'someText' })
    .filter({ has: page.getByRole('button', { data-test-id: 'button' }) })
```

Comment: `.filter({ has: page.getByRole('button', { data-test-id: 'button' }) })` is syntactically invalid JS. Object keys can't have dashes in them.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know , I will test it again . In case If that does not work , I will update it.

Comment: Thanks, let me know when you update so I can remove my comment, or flag it for removal.

Comment: Sure I don't see any issues in accepting and owning our mistakes.

Comment: Are you referring to [our other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77849240/6243352)? If so, I don't mind accepting my mistakes and improving, as long as they're actually mistakes. In that case, I'd be happy to be set straight, but you haven't proposed an actual improvement or solution yet or responded to my feedback, so I have no course of action. Feel free to respond in that thread and tell me what I should be doing that's better than logging a top-level error, which is perfectly normal practice as far as I've ever seen.