# How to loop through json object with playwright

Tags: json, typescript, playwright

hello I have this code below that makes an api call to the url.

```
const [response] = await Promise.all([
        page.waitForResponse(res =>
            res.status() ==200
            &&
            res.url() == 'https://apples.com/members/msg/get_inbox?filter=all&unread_only=0&last_msg_id=0'
            &&
            res.body().then(b=>{
                // console.log(b)
                return b.includes("my_id");
            })
        ),
        await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Continue' }).click()
    ])
```

When I console.log(b) I get an object back that looks like this

```
{
    "threads": [
        {
            "thread_id": "116E451645000000",
            "unread_total": "1",
            "total": "1",
            "newest_unread_msg_id": "21011917985",
            "newest_msg_id": "21011917985",
            "other_id": "99",
            "message": "Hello and welcome. Get verified in less than a minute! It's quick and easy.\r\n\r\nThanks for joining us! &#128536;",
            "msg_id": "21011917985",
            "createdtime": "2024-01-18T00:37:42-05:00",
            "sender_id": "99",
            "thread_expire": null,
            "my_id": 8913,
            "billing_url": "\/\/apples.com\/members\/billing\/join\/?billing_header=msg_expire&sid=99"
        }
    ],
    "users": [
        {
            "id": "8913",
            "online_status": "ONLINE",
            "username": "Bensure240",
            "membership": "LIONHEART",
            "age": "18",
            "gender": "Man",
            "email_validated": "N",
        },
}
```

I want to only console.log the value of "threads[12]" which is "my_id". If I do `return b[0][12]` I get an error that the type is any and 0 cannot be used to index

Im trying to console log the value of "my_id" and only log just that. The issue is how Im iterating through the object

Comment: `res.body().then(b=>{
                // console.log(b)
                return b.includes("my_id");
            }` will always resolve to true because it will return a promise and promise is truthly.

Comment: Do you want to use this value in the response body as part of the predicate to determine which response to stop waiting for, or do you just want to access it normally after the response arrives? I assume the former and updated your title accordingly. If the latter, do the `res.body()` stuff outside the callback, after the `response` variable exists.

Comment: @ggorlen I want to access it normally after the response arrives. Is it possible to do something like b.index[0]  to just get the my_id?

Comment: @hardkoded I originally upvoted your comment, but upon further investigation, apparently it's OK to return a promise from `waitForResponse`--it will be awaited by Playwright and the resolved truthiness will be used instead of the promise object's truthiness. You can test this in the bottom code block of my [example below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77849240/6243352)--change `.length === 100` to something invalid like `.length === 99` and it'll time out.

Comment: That’s interesting @ggorlen. I still don’t understand how that might work because you don’t return a promise you return a Boolean. I’ll take a look at it!

Comment: @hardkoded I think I am because `42 && true && new Promise()` returns a promise. I'll try to write it more clearly, since if the ordering is different or there are multiple promises, it'll cause problems.

Comment: ahhh that's true @ggorlen

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `waitForResponse` callback is supposed to do one thing: validate whether a given response is the one you're looking for. To do this, it should return a boolean or a promise that resolves to a truthy value. Most of the time, you just want to check the URL, method and status, but it's also possible to use the body as a predicate (see bottom of this post). Technically, your `res.body().then(b=>{` resolves to true, so this should work, but it doesn't help with your main goal of accessing the property you want in your main line of code after the response arrives. Try something like:

```js
const [response] = await Promise.all([
  page.waitForResponse(res =>
    res.status() === 200 &&
    res.url() === 'https://apples.com/members/msg/get_inbox?filter=all&unread_only=0&last_msg_id=0'
  ),
  page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Continue' }).click()
]);
const data = await response.json();
console.log(data.threads[0].my_id);

// or to print all my_ids:
for (const e of data.threads) {
  console.log(e.my_id);
}
```

Note that I removed the `await` before `page.getByRole`. Almost always, you want to pass promises to `Promise.all()`, not their resolved values. `await`ing the click means it'll run and resolve before the `waitForResponse` gets a chance to register, causing the response to never be captured.

If you're not sure how to find the key you want in the JSON, you can [use this tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68460317/6243352) (make sure to close your `]` and remove trailing commas so your JSON is valid).

In case it helps, here's a runnable proof of concept:

```js
const playwright = require("playwright"); // ^1.39.0

const sampleHTML = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<button>click me</button>
<script>
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", e => {
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
});
</script></body></html>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await playwright.firefox.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(sampleHTML);
  const [response] = await Promise.all([
    page.waitForResponse(res =>
      res.status() === 200 &&
      res.url() === "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    ),
    page.click("button"),
  ]);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data[0].title);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

As mentioned above, if you want to wait for a response with a particular piece of data in the body, `waitForResponse` will await any promises you return, so something like the following is possible:

```js
page.waitForResponse(res =>
  // If a synchronous boolean condition fails, return false
  res.status() === 200 &&
  res.url() === "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts" &&

  // Otherwise, if synchronous checks pass, return a promise
  // that resolves to a boolean, which Playwright will await.
  // Note that we can only return one promise if we're using '&&', and
  // that promise needs to be the last operand in the condition chain.
  res.json().then(data => data[0].userId === 1 && data.length === 100)
)
```

This is a bit more precise than using a substring match on the body. Note that the promise needs to be the last part of the boolean condition so it's implicitly returned and can be awaited by Playwright.

Comment: this was it! Thank you so much! the tool you built is really useful!

Comment: ".catch(err => console.error(err))" - the way currently errors are caught in this answer , is anti pattern as it will swallow any errors. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896442/why-is-catcherr-console-errorerr-discouraged

Comment: @VishalAggarwal I'm logging the errors in top-level code, not swallowing them in a function and giving an undefined return value. In the link you gave, that's a low-level function that's being called by other code. In the code here, the logging happens at top level, so there's no return value of undefined to deal with. Generally, the top-level calling code _should_ deal with the possibility that a promise throws, and usually that entails logging it. The only alternative is the program crashes. So there's no antipattern here.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50896873/6243352) in the link you shared: "On it's own, catching errors and logging them is fine at the end of a promise chain", which is exactly what's happening here, this is effectively `main()` code.

Comment: Simply, If you catch something  and do nothing else to handle it like providing a sensible fallback result , then you are just suppressing it. I had to mention it finally as you are doing it repeatedly in most of your answers.The people following your answers may also miss errors in their code.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal Again, I think you're misunderstanding the post you linked. Did you [read the link I shared above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896442/why-is-catcherr-console-errorerr-discouraged/50896873#50896873)? It's OK to log at the top-level caller at the end of the promise chain--there is no result because there's no caller.

Comment: What alternative do you recommend? Can you share an example so I can understand what you're actually suggesting? The only other alternative to logging the error is crashing with an uncaught promise rejection error, or displaying nothing. It sounds like your advice is effectively "never catch any errors and just let the program crash", since that's the only other possible non-silent approach. If you mostly write tests instead of normal scripts, you may not be aware of the typical patterns. The test runner you use basically does something similar to this, catch errors in the test code and log.

Comment: If you take my boilerplate, add an error, then run the code, then run it again without the `catch` block, you'll see it's basically the exact same result. You see the full error, except without the distracting internal error `node:internal/process/promises:288 triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);` which is essentially what I'm handling. Nobody will miss any errors with my boilerplate because I'm logging them, exactly as Node does when you don't catch the error!