# Playwright JavaScript: How to wait for a network request with a particular request payload?

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, playwright

It is easy to wait for a request if they have unique endpoints.
But how do we wait for a particular request if all the endpoints are same, but the request payload varies, eg GraqhQL middle layer.
In this case all the backend calls are done using `https://myapplication.com/graphql-v2`, but the request payload differs.
I want to intercept this request where payload contains the string `getUserDetails`

something on similar lines, but better :

```
const response = await page.waitForResponse(
      (request) => request.url().includes('/graphql-v2') && request.body().includes('getUserDetails')
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your post mentions "request", but you're using `waitForResponse`. If you want to wait for a request, you can use something like this example:

```js
const playwright = require("playwright"); // ^1.41.2

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><script>
fetch("https://www.example.com/graphql-v2", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({query: "getUserDetails"})
})
  .then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) throw Error(res.statusText);
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
</script></body></html>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await playwright.firefox.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const requestFound = page.waitForRequest(req =>
    req.url().includes("/graphql-v2") &&
    /\bgetUserDetails\b/.test(JSON.parse(req.postData()).query)
  );
  await page.setContent(html);
  const request = await requestFound;
  console.log(JSON.parse(await request.postData()));
    // => { query: 'getUserDetails' }
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

To intercept a response based on its body, those involve a promise to parse the body. See the bottom of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77849240/6243352) for an explanation. In short, you can return a promise instead of a boolean from the callback to `waitForResponse`, which Puppeteer will await and use its resolved value as a boolean.

Here's a minimal, complete example:

```js
const playwright = require("playwright");

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><script>
fetch("https://httpbin.org/post", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({query: "getUserDetails"})
})
  .then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) throw Error(res.statusText);
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
</script></body></html>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await playwright.firefox.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const responseFound = page.waitForResponse(
    res =>
      res.status() === 200 &&
      res.url().includes("httpbin.org/post") &&
      res
        .json()
        .then(data => /\bgetUserDetails\b/.test(data.json.query))
  );
  await page.setContent(html);
  const response = await responseFound;
  console.log((await response.json()).json);
    // => { query: 'getUserDetails' }
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Finally, if you want to intercept a response based on the request body, which I think is your actual use case, you could do something like:

```js
const response = await page.waitForResponse(
  res =>
    res.status() === 200 &&
    res.url().includes("/graphql-v2") &&
    /\bgetUserDetails\b/.test(
      JSON.parse(res.request().postData()).query
    )
);
```

The difference from your attempt is that I've renamed the parameter `res` (response) to clarify what the object really is, then used `.request().postData()` to pull the request payload. The regex is added for a bit of precision, but you can use `includes` if you want.

If this doesn't work, a reproducible example of the site (or a mock site like I've shown) would be useful so I can provide a precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

another way to catch request payload and, if needed, to check whether the payload has some specified value/data or not is as following. I am using it in my test cases

```
    test('Test case to wait for request payload', async ({ page }) => {

        let payloadData = '';
        const keysAndValuesToCheck = {
            properties: {
                'Value 1': 'true',
                'Value 2': 'false',
                'Value 3': 'username',
                'Value 4': 'email'
            }
        };

        // Act
        // Perform all the actions untill the point where you expect the request 
        //Specify the request to intercept
        const requestPromise = page.waitForRequest("https://yourreqesthere.com");

        const request = await requestPromise;

        // Once the request is received, capture its payload data
        if (request) {
            try {
                payloadData = await request.postData();
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error reading request payload:', error);
            }
        } else {
            console.error('Request not received within the timeout period');
        }
        //You might get encoded payload data which you would have to decode and if you want,
        // you can convert it to json
        if (typeof payloadData === 'string') {
            // Once you have the payloadData, decode and parse it
            const encodedJsonString = payloadData.split('=')[1];
            const decodedJsonString = decodeURIComponent(encodedJsonString);
            const jsonData = JSON.parse(decodedJsonString);
            console.log("Payload after jsonoiding : ", jsonData);
        }
         
         // On this jsonData, you can see the url and make assertions on it
        // Now you can assert if the values are in the payload

        await expect(await checkKeys(jsonData,keysAndValuesToCheck)).toBe(true);
    }); 

    checkKeys(jsonData, keysAndValues) {
        
        let mismatches = [];
    
        for (const item of jsonData) {
          const properties = item.properties;
    
          // Check properties
          if (keysAndValues.hasOwnProperty('properties')) {
            const propertiesToCheck = keysAndValues.properties;
            for (const key in propertiesToCheck) {
              const expectedValueAsString = String(propertiesToCheck[key]);
              const actualValueAsString = properties[key] !== undefined ? String(properties[key]) : undefined;
              if (actualValueAsString !== expectedValueAsString) {
                mismatches.push(key);
              }
            }
          }
        }
    
        if (mismatches.length > 0) {
          console.log("Keys that do not match the criteria:", mismatches.join(', '));
          return false;
        } else {
          console.log("All the values matched");
          return true;
        }
      }
```